# Is there a way to verify social media links of a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am project owner of a community application built on Ruby on Rails: My question is about social network verifications.

We ask the user to add his/her social media profiles to his public profile of the community. 
At the moment the user can simply put e.g. his/her Facebook URL to his profile, same for pinterest profile, Twitter and so on, but there is no validation for the urls, at the end of the day the user can add anything he wants, also blablabla

Is there a way to verify if his/her entries are valid? 
Token, API, validation test?

Any hint is welcome,
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Most Social Networks have APIs and you can ask the user to link his account on your application to his/her account on a specific network if he/she wants to show profiles on these Networks.

For Example, you can use the Ruby [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) gem to communicate with the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com). You can create a Facebook Application and link it to your website, then ask the user to grant your Facebook App the minimal default permissions, these will be sufficient to get the Facebook profile URL of the account that was acutally linked, i.e verified.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful, unfortunately not all social networks have an API ready at the moment like slideshare ...